# Set background color to HighChart xAxis labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I set background color to HighChart xAxis labels.

I tried the below but no luck

xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        labels: {
            rotation: 90,
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E',
                    fill: '#000',
                    backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                }
        },
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
    }

Thanks in Advance
Navin

Comment: Just in case, it's possible, see [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242302/highchart-background-color-of-axis) answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't. The xAxis object does not have the attribute backgroundColor.

Comment: is tat possible to show the full text of xAxis on hover? Note: Bydefault, the text are restricted by 15characters

Comment: This answer should not be accepted. Yes, xAxis object doesn't have that attribute, but it is very easy to set background-color on axis labels with flag useHTML and formatter

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @dgw is not correct.

It's possible: you can set use HTML flag and add your own css style.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242302/highchart-background-color-of-axis)

Answer (score 1):

While @dgw is technically correct in stating that the x-axis does not have a `backgroundColor` property, there are alternatives you can use to achieve this effect.

- [Highcharts.js - Background color of axis only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744343/highcharts-js-background-color-of-axis-only): The accepted answer in this post shows how to use the `renderer.rect()` function to draw a colored box at the bottom of your chart, behind the x-axis labels.
- [How to format column chart data labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227679/how-to-format-column-chart-data-labels): My answer in this post shows how to draw a similar rectangle, but based on the chart's current dimensions vs. fixed values.
- [Highchart: Background color of Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242302/highchart-background-color-of-axis): The answers in this post, which was cited by @dyingangel666, also show how to set a background for certain intervals in your x-axis. I used the answer from @Mark as inspiration for my own solution.

I hope these resources will be helpful for others who come across this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 xAxis: {
        labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<span class="xaxis-label">' + (this.value).toFixed(2) + '</span>';
            }
            
        }
    }
```

then in css file

```
.xaxis-label {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 0px 5px;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

Does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this could be a little tricky and but here are the steps I followed to fix it for me.

set chart Background to a color you want your xAxis and yAxis to have

```
 chart: {
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
         },
```

then ass a polygon series to chart with max out y and x-axis with desired chart background

```
 series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Extremely Bad',
                        type: 'polygon',
                        color: '#fff', // desired background for plot area
                        zIndex: 0,
                         data: []
                    },
                    {
                    name: '',
                    type: 'scatter',  // desired series
                    data: [],

                   }]
```

and add z index to xAxis and y-axis to show gridlines

Answer (score 0):

Use only useHtml:true in your labels object
{
useHTML: true,
formatter(val: any) {
const category = props?.xAxis?.categories;

```
          const findedItem = category.find(
            (item: any) => item.count === val.value
          );

          
          return `<span
          style="
          padding:2px 4px;
          color: #fff;
          background: #000"

        >
          ${val.value ? formatPrice(val.value) : 0}
        </span>`;
        },
      }
}
```