# Highcharts.js - Background color of axis only

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

I'm using highcharts and need to set the background color of only the x and y axis. See attached:

[image]

So what I need is to set a background color on the x-axis that is different from the dark gray of the graph (right now they are obviously the same)

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how to go about it? I've been through the highcharts API [Highstock API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) extensively, but couldn't find anything specifically for this.

Thank you again for your time and help!

Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try:

> ```
>  rendered a rectangle and positioned it to the bottom of the graph.
> ```

```
chart.renderer.rect(0/*position on X-axis*/, 275/*position on Y-axis*/, 680/*width*/ , 25/*height*/, 00)
         .attr({
            'stroke-width': 0,
            stroke: '#888888',
            fill: '#888888',
            zIndex: 3
         })
         .add();
```

Read more: `highchart renderer`

x-asis does not have backgroundColor [Set background color to HighChart xAxis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608328/set-background-color-to-highchart-xaxis-labels)

Hope this help.