# Highchart: Background color of Axis

Tags: highcharts

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744343/highcharts-js-background-color-of-axis-only).

In reply its written that we can have background color by making a rectangle.

My question is how I can get `x` and `Y` position of all the ticks on axis. I will need it because I want background color only on alternate dates.

Thanks

Comment: do you want background color only  for labels

Comment: like this: http://i40.tinypic.com/5k264h.png
Color on alternative day only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use `labels.formatter` with background and `useHTML` flag? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AeV7h/

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Foobar'],

        labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<span class="hc-label">' + this.value + '</span>';
            }
        }
    },
```

And CSS:

```
.hc-label {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I want the colored background not only on label, but on whole the axis part between 2 days. As in the picture here: i40.tinypic.com/5k264h.png

Comment: In that case, you need to draw rects as you said. To get start/end values use `chart.x/yAxis[0].toPixels()`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/AeV7h/1/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick example that shades between the 2nd and 4th ticks:

```
var tickStart = 1;
var tickEnd = 3;

$(function () {

   var rect = null;
   function drawRect(chart){
       if (rect){
           rect.element.remove();   
       }        

        var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];  
        var pixStart = xAxis.toPixels (xAxis.tickPositions[tickStart], false);
        var pixEnd = xAxis.toPixels (xAxis.tickPositions[tickEnd], false);
        rect = chart.renderer.rect(pixStart, chart.chartHeight - xAxis.bottom, pixEnd - pixStart , 25, 00)
        .attr({
           'stroke-width': 0,
           stroke: '#888888',
           fill: '#888888',
           zIndex: 3
        })
        .add();
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    drawRect(this);
                },
                redraw: function(){
                    drawRect(this);
                }
            }        
        },
        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            animation: false,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]     
        }]
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MJ6U6/2/).

[image]

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that if you resize the chart  the drawn rectangle will be in the wrong place. You will need to implement the redraw() function and move the rectangle.

Comment: Good stuff Mark! I notice that you're removing it and redrawing it - I've got it working by just calling the .attr() method and updating the x and y co-ords. Maybe it's a bit faster, but yours is a lot cleaner.