# Highcharts datalabels with gradient color

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

Is it possible to somehow trick in a gradient color for the datalabels in Highcharts??

[This link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) shows a workaround to add gradient to a normal text. I have tried a few ways myself to add this into highcharts, but my ways seems to be overridden at some point.

In my case, the website will ***always*** run in a Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out when I searched for my question a little differently, I found this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242302/highchart-background-color-of-axis) showing how to add a background to the datalabels, and more importantly, how to treat the labels as HTML. Using this technique, I could use the information from my question link to color my labels :)

```
dataLabels: 
{
    useHTML: true,
    format: '<span class="my-class" style="...">My label</span>',
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pm8c3dag/1/)